# attribute routing is not working with a multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[Route("employee/released/{year:regex(\\d{4})}/{month:regex(\\d{2}):range(1,12)}")]
public ActionResult ByReleaseDate(int year,int month)
{
    return Content(year+"/"+month);
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem statement. What exactly is it doing? How is that different from what you expect it to do.

Comment: I want to make a constraint to year and month

Comment: but with this statement it just make a constraint on month only

Comment: http://localhost:65128/employee/Released/22015/05   look this 5 digits for year is okay and the constraint is not working